# grep command to view limited text

Tags: grep

i have a large text file containing these values

```
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x
https://www.google.com/?x=zzzzzzzzzzz
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x&b=x
https://www.google.com/admin?a=2&b=3
https://www.google.com/admin?a=a&b=f
```

i want to grep links which have same parameter like this

```
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x
https://www.google.com/?x=zzzzzzzzzzz
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x&b=x
```

i don't want to see different value having same parameter only i want the link having parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an easy job for grep or normal text tool, because the parameter order doesn't matter.

Quick and dirty solution for the given example:

```
kent$  cat f
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x
https://www.google.com/?x=zzzzzzzzzzz
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x&b=x
https://www.google.com/admin?a=2&b=3
https://www.google.com/admin?a=a&b=f

kent$  awk -F'=[^&]*&?' '!a[$1,$2,$3]++' f
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x
https://www.google.com/?x=zzzzzzzzzzz
https://www.google.com/admin?a=x&b=x
```